# .NET Why is Nonconcurrent GC taking a long time suspending threads

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I'm currently profiling my application using PerfView.
as you can see in the [profiling results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uHTr.png), at some point a blocking GC was triggered (GC Index 6439), and although the Pause time is quite large (15622ms), most of that pause time is suspending time (15507ms).

My question is, what could be the reason for such a long suspending time?

Comment: Read e.g. https://mattwarren.org/2016/08/08/GC-Pauses-and-Safe-Points/. Perhaps you have long calls into native code whcih the GC can't insert poll locations into, or code which does a lot in a tight loop which doesn't have any GC poll locations?

Comment: @canton do you have any idea how can we detect if any of those issues exist?

Comment: Your gen0 survival rate is very low. Maybe you're allocating a lot of temporary objects and the GC is busy cleaning them up?

Comment: Such long suspension time is definitely a bug. What .NET version you are using? You should create an issue in the .NET runtime repository.